# Using Julia Flux to build a simple neural network

Tags: neural-network, julia, flux.jl

I have a dataset of images (https://www.kaggle.com/iarunava/cell-images-for-detecting-malaria), and I want to use a neural network to know if one picture is a uninfected cell or not.
So I arranged my data to get 4 variables :

```
X_tests, Y_tests, X_training, Y_training
```

Each of these variable is of type `Array{Array{Float64,1},1}`

And I have a function to build a simple neural network (that comes from an example https://smist08.wordpress.com/2018/09/24/julia-flux-for-machine-learning/):

```
function simple_nn(X_tests, Y_tests, X_training, Y_training)
    input = 100*100*3
    hl1 = 32
    m = Chain(
      Dense(input, 32, relu),
      Dense(32, 2),
      softmax) |> gpu

    loss(x, y) = crossentropy(m(x), y)

    accuracy(x, y) = mean(onecold(m(x)) .== onecold(y))

    dataset = [(X_training,Y_training)]
    evalcb = () -> @show(loss(X_training, Y_training))
    opt = ADAM(params(m))

    Flux.train!(loss, dataset, opt, cb = throttle(evalcb, 10))

    println("acc X,Y ", accuracy(X_training, Y_training))

    println("acc tX, tY ", accuracy(X_tests, Y_tests))
end
```

And I get this error after executing `simple_nn(X_tests, Y_tests, X_training, Y_training)` :

```
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("matrix A has dimensions (32,30000), vector B has length 2668")
...
```

The error is on this line : `Flux.train!(loss, dataset, opt, cb = throttle(evalcb, 10))`

I don't know what the functions are doing, what argument they take, what they are returning and I can't find any documentation on the internet. I can only find examples.
So I have two questions : How can I make this work for my dataset? And Is there a documentation for Flux functions, like for sklearn? (like this for example : https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html)

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a self-contained MWE? I think your `X_training` is not of dimension `3*100*100`x something, and it is in fact 2688 by something.

Your first layer is `Dense(input, 32, relu)` and input is `3*100*100`, so it's expect an input where one of dimension is `3*100*100` which you don't satisfy.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to replace

```
dataset = [(X_training,Y_training)]
```

with

```
dataset = zip(X_training,Y_training)
```

zip actually pairs the training data 1 of X with 1 of Y and thus turns a tuple of vectors into a vector of tuples. I would guess that your training data has 2688 samples?